# form_for nested resources(post, comment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have one question about form_for with nested resources. I create something like blog, with posts,comments, comments on comments(like replies).And I have an issue. Then I try to make comment it: "Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :get_parent rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found"

**new.html.erb for comments:**

```
<div class= "container" %>
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**My comments controller:**

```
   before_filter :get_parent

  def new
    @comment = @parent.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @comment = @parent.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to posts_path(@comment.post), :notice => 'Thank you for your comment!'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :title, :user_id, :commentable_id, :commentable_type)
  end


  def get_parent
    @parent = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) if params[:post_id]
    @parent = Comment.find_by_id(params[:comment_id]) if params[:comment_id]

    redirect_to root_path unless defined?(@parent)
  end
end
```

**post model:**

```
has_many :comments, as: :commentable
belongs_to :user

 def post
    commentable.is_a?(Post) ? commentable : commentable.post
  end
```

**comment model:**

```
belongs_to :user

belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

**routes:**

```
 resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  resources :comments do
    resources :comments 
  end
```

**post_show.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<div class="body">
  <%= @post.body %>  
</div>

<h2>Comments</h2>

<p><%= link_to 'Add a Comment', new_post_comment_path(@post) %></p>

<ul class="comment_list">
  <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @post.comments %>
</ul>
```

github repo with app: https://github.com/Dmitry96/dasasd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `new` form does not pass neither `post_id` nor `comment_id` parameter. It should be eather in the form action url or in the form body.

I can not see all the picture, but I think you have to add parent id to the form action url. It is `/comments` now, has no parent id parameter in it. It must be `/posts/:post_id/comments` or `/comments/:comment_id/comments`.

Change your form to:

```
<%= form_for [@parent, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey bro, thank you. I switched for this form and in controller to (comment_params). It starts to works